# Signalr-objc getting Return value

Tags: objective-c, signalr

I am using signalr-objc currently and trying to make an app that interacts with another web app. The hub has been written so that it returns values and the javascript is able to get these and perform certain actions depending on the return.

I want to try and do the same with in objective-c but I am not sure how to write it. I use this line to join a group.

```
[myhub invoke:@"joinGroup" withArgs:joinParam];
```

and something like

```
int join = [myhub invoke:@"joinGroup" withArgs:joinParam];
```

does not seem right. So is there some way of doing this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `-invoke:withArgs:` returns no value, you're not doing the right thing trying to assign a value to `join`.

If you need to determine if there was a server response, you'd be better off using the alternate `-invoke:withArgs:continueWith:`. The block you provide to the latter argument receives an object (a reply from the server); at the very least, you could check it inside that block to be sure it's not `nil`.

Comment: so do I perform a check on what I receive in continueWith??

Comment: also continueWith doesnt seem to be in the signalR classes at all

Comment: I know only what I read in the documentation for signalr-objc. The description is [here](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/wiki/SignalR-iOS-Client-(Hubs)), about halfway down the page.

Comment: Ya I read that but when you implement it, it gives an error and opening the files shows theres no continueWith. There is completionHandler which may be the same thing